# Add Facebook like button after all image in string

Tags: php, facebook

How can I add facebook like button, after all image in string.

For example:

```
<p>This is some text. This is some text. This is image: <img src='url'/>. This is some tekst. This is new image: <img src='url'></p>
```

I want change to this:

```
<p>This is some text. This is some text. This is image: <img src='url'/><facebook like buuton>. This is some tekst. This is new image: <img src='url'> <facebook like button></p>
```

Comment: And what do you want to like ?, the img url ?, or the current url of the window ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery :

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("img").each(function() {  
    $(this).after('<facebook like buuton>');
  });  
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/4893/)